# На объект сущности не могут ссылаться несколько экземпляров интерфейса IEntityChangeTracker

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Хочу создать приложение по типу такого https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/20/building-a-simple-todo-application-with-asp-net-identity-and-associating-users-with-todoes/, т.е. когда есть пользователи и они создают сущности

есть класс Store

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace RolesIdentityApp.Models
{
    public class Store
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int LikesCount { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }
}
```

модель IdentityModels.cs

```
namespace RolesIdentityApp.Models
{
    // Чтобы добавить данные профиля для пользователя, можно добавить дополнительные свойства в класс ApplicationUser. Дополнительные сведения см. по адресу: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Обратите внимание, что authenticationType должен совпадать с типом, определенным в CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Здесь добавьте утверждения пользователя
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

и контроллер

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,Address,LikesCount")] Store store)
        {
            var currentUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                store.User = currentUser;
                db.Stores.Add(store);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(store);
        }
```

когда создаю объект пишет
На объект сущности не могут ссылаться несколько экземпляров интерфейса IEntityChangeTracker
http://prntscr.com/ipzao0 
Что не такделаю?

Comment: К сожалению, я никогда не делал приложения на ASP.NET, поэтому код контроллера мне мало, что даёт в понимании того, что происходит. Но, вот буквально пару часов назад я столкнулся с аналогичной проблемой, как у вас. В моём приложении есть такая функция: https://ibb.co/fqLeQH. В моей функции в аргументах есть переменная — record типа EntityRecord. Как я решил проблему: я добавил 39 строчку. Если в моём варианте этого не делать, то у переменной record старый контекст, следовательно, нужно обновить его. Аналогично сделайте и для вашей переменной store типа Store в плане обновления контекста.

Comment: Просто могу предположить, что ваша проблема из-за переменной store типа Store и с этим вам нужно что-то делать в ASP.NET. Но я не уверен в этом.

Comment: добавил 39 строчку? что имеете ввиду

Comment: Я обновляю для переменной record контекст, вернее даже через переменную record делаю поиск такой записи в базе данных. Вы не можете просто взять и сделать вот так: 'db.Stores.Add(store)', поскольку сначала нужно найти эту запись в БД через вашу переменную store, далее вы что-то делаете с найденной вашей записью, а потом делаете это: 'db.Stores.Add(store)'. Как это будет выглядеть у вас лично, я не знаю, но судя по коду контроллера, вы тоже используете технологию Entity Framework, значить вам нужно примерно также сделать, как и я на 39 строчке.

Comment: я создаю с нуля сущность, нечего искать

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Проблема решилась переносом Store.cs в IdentityModels.cs

Store удалил, IdentityModels стало

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace RolesIdentityApp.Models
{
    // Чтобы добавить данные профиля для пользователя, можно добавить дополнительные свойства в класс ApplicationUser. Дополнительные сведения см. по адресу: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string About { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
        public string ImageMimeType { get; set; }
        public int Likes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Обратите внимание, что authenticationType должен совпадать с типом, определенным в CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Здесь добавьте утверждения пользователя
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class Store
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public int LikesCount { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Store> Stores { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вы наверное всё-таки что-то сделали кроме переноса модели Store.cs в IdentityModels.cs. Сегодня у меня возникла идентичная ситуация. Тоже делал по тому же гайду, что и вы. Такая же ошибка на той же самой строчке. Но мне перенос модели в IdentityModels.cs не помог, всё равно та же ошибка.

Upd.

Решил проблему следующим образом. В модели Store должно быть не только свойство User, а еще и UserId

```
public string UserId { get; set; }
[ForeignKey("UserId")]
public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
```

И в контроллере собственно не нужно получать сам объект текущего User'a, а нужно передавать просто UserId

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Description,Address,LikesCount")] Store store)
    {
        //var currentUser = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        var curUserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //store.User = currentUser;
            store.UserId = curUserId;

            db.Stores.Add(store);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(store);
    }
```

В модели юзера у меня еще есть конструктор, но не знаю, влияет ли он в данном случае на результат

```
public virtual ICollection<Store> Stores { get; set; }
        public ApplicationUser() : base()
        {
            Stores= new List<Store>();
        }
```